# How to copy npm package files to my local project?

Tags: javascript, npm

It could be a duplicate question, but I could not find the answer I wanted, no matter how I tried to find it. So, I ask.

**What I wanted:**

Move the file in node_modules to my project, so that I can use it while editing the file

[image]

**First try:**

Moved the file I wanted to edit
And only modify the import path for that file
[image]
[image]

**result:**

[image]

**weird:**

All modified paths are correct

i.e. I can move to that imported file through that path in the IDE.

[image]

**Example repo:**

https://github.com/YahngSungho/dfsfdsfsfdsfwfsd/tree/help/npmToLocal1
Especially:
https://github.com/YahngSungho/dfsfdsfsfdsfwfsd/tree/help/npmToLocal1/src/components/editableText

**Second try:**

I moved all of the files imported as well as the file I want to modify, into the project.

[image]

**result:**

[image]

[image]

**My opinion:** 
It seems to be related to Typescript or commonjs. But I do not know how to make it work.

**Example repo:** 
https://github.com/YahngSungho/dfsfdsfsfdsfwfsd/tree/help/npmToLocal2
Especially:
https://github.com/YahngSungho/dfsfdsfsfdsfwfsd/tree/help/npmToLocal2/src/components/list/editableText/components/editable-text

If anyone knows how to solve the problem, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I am not getting why you are using the node_modules like this?

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal What do you mean? As mentioned in the question, I want to modify the file of package and integrate it into my code.

Comment: Node Modules are not meant for modification you should extend them according to your need but you should not modify them

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal That's why I was trying to move files in node_module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options for you:

**Solution 1:** You could manually [monkey-patch](https://techsparx.com/nodejs/howto/monkey-patch-npm-module.html) the module in question:

Here is how to do it (general approach):

Create a new file named `ModifiedEditableText.tsx`

Then in that file:

```
import { EditableText } from "@blueprintjs/core";

const newModule = {};

// First, copy over all the fields from the original module
for (let fieldName in EditableText) {
    newModule[fieldName] = EditableText[fieldName];
}

// Then write new implementations of any function you want to change
newModule.function1 = function(arg, arg2, arg3) {
    // new function implementation
    // To call the original function do:
    EditableText.function1();
}

export default newModule;
```

**Solution 2:** Fork the module, do your change, submit a PR and hope that it is merged (probably not gonna happen)

**Solution 3:** Fork the module, do your change(s) and import that module in your code instead of the official library

**Solution 4:** Use a library to monkey patch your component, here are some examples of such libraries:

- https://github.com/ds300/patch-package
- https://github.com/lukehorvat/overwrite

Comment: I am very grateful for your reply. I will try and comment again.

Comment: I tried the solutions you mentioned. After all, I decided to use 'patch-package'.

Comment: At first I tried Solution 1. However, when I assign {} to newModule, I got an error that it should be a class or function, not an object. And when I assign a class, I got an error that I called the class, not the function. And when I assign a function, I got an error saying that .render () can not be called. I'm not sure why this problem occurs. Anyway I would like to thank you again.